# Is this sort of structure/scenario in a unit test project possible?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structure, xunit

I'm new to the concept of unit testing and have started using xUnit framework to write my tests. I have a question that I would like to ask about unit testing.

In my test project, I'm going to have an interface which contains all the common test scenarios which will then be implemented by a base class. I didn't want to repeat writing the same code for the same test over and over in each test class files so in the base class I will have the implementation for each of the methods outlined in the interface but marked as virtual as it can be overwritten by the concrete test class when it needs to be.

For example:

```
public interface IPersonTests
{
    void ValidateAge();
    void ValidateExperience();
    void ValidateAddress();
}
```

```
public abstract class BasePersonTests : IPersonTests
{
    public virtual void ValidateAge()
    {
        // method implementation
    }

    public virtual void ValidateExperience()
    {
        // method implementation
    }

    public void ValidateAddress()
    {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

```
public class PersonA : BasePersonTests
{
    [Fact]
    public override void ValidateAge()
    {
        // different method implementation to the one specified in the base class
    }
}
```

Is it okay to have a code structure like the above for a unit test project?

Comment: Do you see possible caveats of your solution?

Comment: @Fabio, the only thing that I can think of currently is whether I will really need the interface file. I feel like I am creating unnecessary files when I can put all of them into an abstract class. The example I've put in the question is shortened down but I was planning to have multiple interfaces with multiple abstract base classes which will cover the common tests for different features.

Comment: Agree that you don't need interface because you already have abstract base class.

Comment: Alternative approach would be - write tests without base class and only when you have multiple test cases which are changes for the same reason, only then would try to "dry" them up ;)